# CKEditor, MongoDB, and NodeJs: Text is displayed in HTML Format

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ckeditor

I'm currently building my first blog site where I'm using CKEditor v4.14.1 to allow the user to make a formatted blog entry. However, the user input is showing on the webpage as HTML instead of formatted text. I'm using MongoDB to store the blog entry as well.

This is the user input:
[image: user input]

And this is the output on the webpage:
[image: output on webpage]

new.ejs

```
<form action="/posts" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="input-area">
    <textarea name="post[body]" id="editor" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor')
</script>
```

MongoDB Post Schema

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  body: String
})

PostSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

controllers/posts.js

```
const Post = require('../models/post');

// Posts Create
async postCreate(req, res, next) {
  let post = new Post(req.body.post);
  post.body = req.body.post.body;
  await post.save();
}
```

show.ejs

```
<div><%= post.body %></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My show.ejs should be

```
<div><%- post.body %></div>
```

instead of

```
<div><%= post.body %></div>
```

Comment: can you view my question i'm having same problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67040895/display-text-from-ckeditor-using-nodejs