# display text from ckeditor using nodejs

Tags: node.js, ckeditor

i have inputted value using ckeditor but i'm getting html tags along with the document how can i show only text

this is my input formant and how i want to show
https://prnt.sc/11a6em6

this is my output format
https://prnt.sc/11a6mdv

this is code to display the text

```
{{#each about}}
    <div class="theme-title-one">
        <h2>{{this.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{this.description}}<p>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

text i'm getting on the display side is

```
<h3><strong>New updates to  program</strong></h3><h4><strong>1.
</strong><i><strong>target sectors have been
 expanded.</strong></i></h4><p>When the program was launched in
 2019, applicants under seven target sectors were accepted. These
 sectors were as follows:</p>
```

i want to display is

#### **New updates to  program**

**1.** ***target sectors have been expanded.***

When the  program was launched in 2019, applicants under seven target sectors were accepted. These sectors were as follows:

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data to be structured then you need to break them up and not use a RTE. The point of an RTE is to allow you to create rich text, so the editor will always insert html, thats the point.

To do what you want to do, you COULD, not that you should parse the response with regex and pull out the H3 as the title and body etc..

This method can work but is a pain.

If the data is to always be in the format you want then you should add a 'title' and 'description' to the DB table, this way you can always get a clean title and body.

Without knowing how things are structured or the use case its a bit difficult to tell but that would be a better way of doing it.

Comment: i have added title and description in the table above i'm showing is the part of description of blog but i want them in different size along with bullet

Comment: If you trying to just change the display then you will use CSS to do that.. 

So just target the specific elements then 

.theme-title-one h3{ font-size:25px }
.theme-title-one h4{ font-size:18px}

But really, the RTE is always going to insert html so that can muck things up

Comment: i'm so confused here these are the inputs from the ckeditor and in blog page i have to display bullets place link use h1 h2 h3....  if i wanted particular line to change i would have done that easily 
doing so for whole page is not easy using css

Comment: samita, I'm sorry but maybe you could provide more details then because your question is not clear as to the issue. From what I can tell the output you are getting is the code posted above correct?.  Again, if that is the case you can change the display with CSS, if not then maybe try providing the full code and output or a sample page to help illustrate it better. CKEditor is an RTE so it will insert html, if you don't want html then use a regular textarea for the input.

Comment: i'm sorry my questions was not so understandable i've edited my post i'll put code of controller also if needed but i dont think there is problem in controllet its the way i'm displaying